# set PATH permanently

Tags: path, centos, .profile

How do I edit my `.profile` file to set a permanent value for my `PATH` variable?

Is there any other file that needs editing? 
(This is on CentOs 6.2)

Comment: Why did you close my question???? What's wrong with asking stuff that one doesn't knwo?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming. You may have better luck with this question at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably want to do this in your shell's rcfile (.bashrc, .zshrc, etc.). You'll want to add something like the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/new/folder/path
```

if you are only looking to append a file path. Or you can get tricky with it and create a path file (for zsh I have a .zpath file). In there you can do something like:

```
PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin"
export PATH
```

Now every time that file is sourced (`source ~/.zpath` for example) it will load those paths into your environment. You can add `source ~/.zpath` to your rcfile so this will happen every time you log in or create a new shell.

Comment: I don't want to append new values to `PATH`. I want to remove some values, and replace some others with new stuff. Should I just put `export PATH= <new path>` in my .bashrc file? (I put this in my .profile file, but it didn't seem to ahve any effect)

Comment: Yea, put that in your .bashrc.

Comment: Thanks! (I don't know how to mark your answer as the `answer`, though). (THere is supposed to be a check symbol, isn't there?)

Comment: Not entirely sure (I haven't asked any questions yet). I thought there was a check image under the upvote/downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
 - Go to /etc/profile 
Go to line # Path manipulation if [ "$EUID" = "0]; then
       pathmunge /sbin
       pathmunge /usr/sbin
       pathmunge /usr/local/sbin

   ***add your path like this- pathmunge /your/path
```

** or you change userid (0 is root) or add more conditions  like

```
   if [ "$EUID" >= "0" ]; then
       pathmunge /sbin
       pathmunge /usr/sbin
       pathmunge /usr/local/sbin 
   ** to find your id type this command at prompt #id
```

And reboot the system

Answer (score 1):

I think make a bashscript
for this you need to use the profile.d /etc/profile could be replaced by an update?

vi /etc/profile.d/path.sh

## !/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/new/folder/path:/opt/anotherpath:/etc/etc/etc

save it and chmod +x /etc/profile.d/path.sh

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question, which ask about "set PATH **permanently**"